# Excel VBA auto switches active sheet without instruction

Tags: excel, vba

Recently upgraded to O365. When running code without any .Activate or .Select commands, when the code finishes, the screen switches to a specific sheet.

Is it possible that using With with Shapes, or .Protect/.Unprotect now activates sheets perhaps?

Interestingly, when stepping into the code, it runs as expected, without switching sheets.

Comment: Can you show your code in your question please? hard to tell whats going on without seeing it.

Comment: I run a for each worksheet routine to protect sheets and the screen definitely flickers while protecting sheets so it does seem to do something akin to activate now. Never had it stop at a different sheet though